# Tensorflow leaking memory at every call to session.run() with finalized graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the tf.data api to feed variable-size image data (LxLx2) to my model, however I notice that I am leaking memory at every iteration. I would expect that the memory use would be determined by the largest image in the dataset, however I can see that memory use is increasing even when processing an image that is smaller than the maximum size seen so far.

[Leaking memory over 100 iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mgZr.png)

When I directly gather the processed features instead of computing the neural network activations, the memory does not seem to leak.

[Expected memory use (forgoing NN computation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRA3H.png)

It seems that the most common cause of this type of problem is dynamically adding nodes to the graph, however I call graph.finalize() prior to the iteration and do not catch any error.

I am using python 3.5.4 and tensorflow 1.10 and running the computation on the CPU only.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sys import argv

# Data preparation
def record_parser(value):
    keys_to_features = {
        'seq_length': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
        'seq_feat': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32)
        }
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(value, keys_to_features)
    length_ = tf.reshape(parsed['seq_length'].values, [])
    i32_len = tf.cast(length_, dtype=tf.int32)
    features_ = tf.reshape(parsed['seq_feat'].values, [i32_len, i32_len, 2])
    return features_

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
dataset_ = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(argv[1])
dataset_ = dataset_.map(lambda value: record_parser(value))
dataset_ = dataset_.batch(1)
iterator = dataset_.make_one_shot_iterator()
features = iterator.get_next()

# NN part
nn0 = tf.layers.conv2d(features, filters=64, kernel_size=15, padding='SAME',\
 activation=tf.nn.relu)
nn = tf.layers.dense(nn0, units=100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
prediction = tf.layers.dense(nn, 17, activation=None)

var_init_op = tf.group(
                tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                tf.local_variables_initializer()
                )
graph.finalize()

# Iterating over samples
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(var_init_op)
    for i in range(100):
        out_loss = sess.run(prediction)
        #out_loss = sess.run(features)
```

Comment: The issue was resolved by updating to tensorflow 1.13

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Answer here for the benefit of the Community.

The Issue of Memory Leakage when using `tf.data` API in `Tensorflow Version 1.10` is resolved by upgrading to `Tensorflow Version 1.13`.